# C# asp.net: focus error in jquery searchable dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi all, I'm trying to use jquery search dropdown in my asp.net project. After one day usage, i got some problems, I already tried to research but cannot fix. Below, I create a small project to demonstrate my problem:
https://app.box.com/s/u56motrehqii5g9spdbq

The page focus work normal until i put the searchable dropdown script, after type to search and select item, i press Tab to focus to my textbox below, but the focus change to my gridview header column.

My page

```C#
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboData" TabIndex="1">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="A"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtData" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

My .aspx.cs (only for input samples data )

```C#
#region

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;

#endregion

public partial class Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "CCC");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "DDD");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

My master page

```C#
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<script src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="JS/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var flag = false;
    // Load for page, run once in ajax, run every page load in normal page
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").searchable();
    });
    // Load run each ajax callback 
    function pageLoad() {
        if (flag==false) {
            $("select").searchable();
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }
    };
</script>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help, sorry for any inconvenient, this is my first post in stackoverflow.

Comment: nitpicking, but please upgrade jQuery to a version that's not 5 years old

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I upgraded jQuery and it solved my problem.